# Spring SimpleJdbcCall and BeanPropertyRowMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

To get data from database I'm using `SimpleJdbcCall` as it is convenient for stored procedures. Along with it I'm using `BeanPropertyRowMapper` as the no of fields I have to map from resultset is almost 100.

From Spring docs I could see that `BeanPropertyRowMapper` is for convenience and not for performance, as it uses *reflection*. My stored procedure returns one record and this is to be sent as JSON for front end.

I would want to know:

1. Is it correct to use the above mentioned for my use-case or should I switch to a prepared statement and manually mapping from `ResultSet` to POJO?
2. When the fields to be mapped are less and records are more should I switch from `SimpleJdbcCall` to prepared statement and `ResultSet`?

Comment: It already uses a prepared statement. Have you measured the performance, is it a problem? If not leave it as is.

Comment: I could improve the performance by disabling procedureColumnMetaDataAccess. However, it isn't as fast as prepared statement